# LINQ join Entities from HashSet's, Join vs Dictionary vs HashSet performance

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have HashSet's where each stores T, I have written a test application that compares the different relation algorithms that I can think of, however I'm not all pleased with the results that I am getting.

Does there exist more efficient ways of achieving object relations, then the once that I am testing?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace LINQTests
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HashSet<User> UserTable = new HashSet<User>();
            HashSet<UserProperty> UserPropertyTable = new HashSet<UserProperty>();

            #region Lets create some dummy data.

            Console.WriteLine("Please wait while creating dummy data, this can take a while...");
            Console.WriteLine("");

            int rows = 1000000;
            for(int x = 0; x < rows; x++)
            {
                Random rnd = new Random();

                // Add new user.
                User user = new User(string.Format("Joachim-{0}", x));
                if(!UserTable.Add(user))
                {
                    // throw new Exception.
                }
                else
                {
                    UserProperty age = new UserProperty(user, "Age", rnd.Next(25, 30).ToString());
                    if(!UserPropertyTable.Add(age))
                    {
                        // throw new Exception.
                    }

                    UserProperty sex = new UserProperty(user, "Sex", "Male");
                    if (!UserPropertyTable.Add(sex))
                    {
                        // throw new Exception.
                    }

                    UserProperty location = new UserProperty(user, "Location", "Norway");
                    if (!UserPropertyTable.Add(location))
                    {
                        // throw new Exception.
                    }
                }
            }

            #endregion

            #region Lets do some query tests.

            IEnumerable<User> Users;
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            int matches = 0;

            // Lets find all users who are of age 29.
            Console.WriteLine("Finding all users who are of age 29");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-20} | {1,6} | {2,9}", "Search Strategy", "Found", "Time");
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------");

            // Join test.
            stopwatch.Start();

            Users = (from user in UserTable
                     join property in UserPropertyTable on user.Id equals property.UserId
                     where property.Key == "Age" && property.Value == "29"
                     select user);

            matches = Users.Count();
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-20} | {1,6} | {2,6} ms.", "Joining Tables", matches, stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            // Dictionary test.
            stopwatch.Restart();

            var DictionarySearch = (from t in UserPropertyTable where t.Key == "Age" && t.Value == "29" select t).ToDictionary(x => x.UserId);
            Users = (from t in UserTable where DictionarySearch.ContainsKey(t.Id) select t);

            matches = Users.Count();
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-20} | {1,6} | {2,6} ms.", "Dictionary Contain", matches, stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            // HashSet test.
            stopwatch.Restart();

            var HashsetSearch = new HashSet<Guid>(from t in UserPropertyTable where t.Key == "Age" && t.Value == "29" select t.UserId);

            Users = (from t in UserTable where HashsetSearch.Contains(t.Id) select t);

            matches = Users.Count();
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-20} | {1,6} | {2,6} ms.", "HashSet Contain", matches, stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            // Following takes so long that we wont run them!

            //// Array test.
            //stopwatch.Restart();

            //var ArrayMatch = (from t in UserPropertyTable where t.Key == "Age" && t.Value == "29" select t.UserId).ToArray();
            //Users = (from t in UserTable where ArrayMatch.Contains(t.Id) select t);

            //matches = Users.Count();
            //stopwatch.Stop();
            //Console.WriteLine("{0,-20} | {1,6} | {2,6} ms.", "Array Contain", matches, stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);


            //// List test.
            //stopwatch.Restart();

            //var ListMatch = (from t in UserPropertyTable where t.Key == "Age" && t.Value == "29" select t.UserId).ToList();
            //Users = (from t in UserTable where ListMatch.Contains(t.Id) select t);

            //matches = Users.Count();
            //stopwatch.Stop();
            //Console.WriteLine("{0,-20} | {1,6} | {2,6} ms.", "List Contain", matches, stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);


            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------");

            #endregion


            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Hit return to exit...");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public User(string UserName)
        {
            this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            this.UserName = UserName;
        }

        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            User other = obj as User;

            if (other == null)
                return false;

            return this.Id == other.Id;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Id.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    public class UserProperty
    {
        public UserProperty(User user, string key, string value)
        {
            this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            this.UserId = user.Id;
            this.Key = key;
            this.Value = value;
        }

        public Guid Id { get; private set; }
        public Guid UserId {get; private set;}
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            UserProperty other = obj as UserProperty;

            if (other == null)
                return false;

            return this.UserId == other.UserId && this.Key == other.Key;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return string.Format("{0}-{1}", this.UserId, this.Key).GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you search hashsets there is a big question about it on stackoverflow

Comment: Since you are instantiating the random class inside of the loop many items will have exactly the same data due to timing. Maybe that is causing measurement error.

Comment: What are the results and why do they seem bad to you? UserProperty.GetHashcode is probably 10x slower than necessary. That's the only issue I can spot.

Comment: Don't ever ever ever compute `GetHashCode()` using fields/properties that aren't read only in a class. The value of `GetHashCode()` must remain the same during the lifetime of an object.

Comment: Oh yes, I typed this up quickly as the "real world" code that I use, uses a generic T interface for a HashSet repository. But yes each class that has GetHashCode are computed from read only properties.

Comment: @usr, is it the string.Format you are thinking about? But does not that only apply when i add entities to the hashset? Main problem i am having  is beeing able to quickly resolve object relations.

Answer (score 2):

This will make the linq/join comparable to the other methods:

```
var properties = UserPropertyTable
    .Where(p=>p.Key == "Age" && p.Value == "29")
    .ToArray();

Users = (from user in UserTable
         join property in properties
         on user.Id equals property.UserId
         select user);
```

Here is **the fastest (~2X)** I could achieve:

```
var filteredUserIds = new HashSet<Guid>(
        UserPropertyTable
            .Where(p=>p.Key == "Age" && p.Value == "29")
            .Select(p=>p.UserId));

Users = (from user in UserTable
         where filteredUserIds.Contains(user.Id)
         select user);
```

With the output

```
---------------------------------------------------
Search Strategy      |  Found |      Time
---------------------------------------------------
My method            | 210366 |    157 ms.
Dictionary Contain   | 210366 |    325 ms.
HashSet Contain      | 210366 |    325 ms.
---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Very good thinking. The results I get are much the same - still a little longer with the join, but this makes sense due to the linear join required.

Comment: @Enigmativity: Check the other method with a hashset and a where.

Comment: Both my Dictionary Contain and HashSet Contain do not get the benefit from defered LINQ statement. However it seem like the following which is a little slower (5-10%) than both Dict and Hash contain has the benefit from defered LINQ:  
`Users = (from user in UserTable
                     join property in UserPropertyTable.Where(x => x.Key == "Age" && x.Value == "29")
                     on user.Id equals property.UserId
                     select user);`

Test by commenting out: `maches = Users.Count();`

Comment: A bit of further testing reveals that using filtered linq join even out perform dict and hashset approach in many cases, however after a certain size of hashset all approaches eventually gets slow, perhaps there exists better ways of storing and finding entities?

Comment: You can keep them indexed based on what you're looking for (age?).

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few things you can do:

1. GetHashCode is being called for each element added and for each element being probed (how else could the hash table compare the two hash codes?). Equals is being called at least once for each probe. Optimize those. Do not use string.Format(!). It needs to parse the format string and allocate memory. `UserId.GHC() * 37 ^ Name.GHC()` should do.
2. Don't use LINQ. Write manual loops. LINQ has multiple vcalls or delegate calls per item being processed. That adds instructions, stalls the CPU and prevents inlining.
3. Can you precompute data structures? Precompute hash tables or sorted lists. Merging two sorted lists could be faster than using a hash table. This is not built-in to the framework. Lot's of hard, custom code to write for merge joins.
4. Why are you including the `property.Key == "Age" && property.Value == "29"` predicate in the measurements? Will that need to be run for each execution? You can try to optimize that by using integer values instead of strings. Maybe you can precompute an index for `UserPropertyTable` so that you can get the matching elements in constant time.

This should give you 1-10x speedup depending on how much you implement. If you need to go even faster than that I would need to ask some questions first. Often you can find specialized tricks that only apply to particular situations.

Comment: Thanks for pointers! GHC fix alone made queries run about 20~25% quicker! I was hoping I would be able to use LINQ because the data queried are for a REST / Json RPC with a huge amount of exposed methods, the client that I have written uses a Redis data-store with entities stored in memory, which you can read more about here [Object-cache C# Take two](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/93771/75707) (ConcurrentDictionary's which stores HashSet's based on Type) `property.Key == "Age" && property.Value == "29"` was simply an added factor I added to give it a more real world scenario.

Comment: Storing key's with int (enum) also did speed up the process a little but not enough to justify the flexibility string would give me. The property's are meant to be "unknown" extension's to the user object that I might find a need for down the line. Lets call this a flexible data-model, in real world application these relations are not meant specifically for user objects but entirely different objects, the data-model can be flexible depending on parent-records, out of roughly 40~ classes I only need this extend-ability for 3-4 different classes.

Comment: An example of how i would use query in a real world scenario based on the code in example: `Users = (from user in UserTable
                     join property in UserPropertyTable.Where(x => x.Key == "Age" && x.Value == "29")
                     on user.Id equals property.UserId
                     select new { User = user, Properties = property });` Users would then be defined as following: `IEnumerable<object> Users;` as JsonConvert will swallow this without any questions.